# Cannot import zfs volume

Tags: linux, raid, zfs

One of my disks died in a ZFS RAID system, and I have been trying to re-import the volume hoping the system will resilver after inserting a new drive, but no matter what `zpool` command I use, I always get:

```
status: One or more devices are missing from the system.
action: The pool cannot be imported. Attach the missing devices and try again.
```

Three of the disks are seen but for the love of me, I cannot add a new drive or import the volume.
I am running ubuntu MATE 17.10
Please help!

`zpool list -v` prints `no pools available`

```
adeolur@Akure:~$ sudo zpool import
 pool: orisha
 id: 3037127084551751026
 state: UNAVAIL
 status: One or more devices are missing from the system.
 action: The pool cannot be imported. Attach the missing devices and try again.
 see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-6X
 config:
  orisha UNAVAIL missing device
   ata-WDC_WD20EZRX-00DC0B0_WD-WMC300898572 ONLINE
   ata-WDC_WD20EZRX-00DC0B0_WD-WMC301198182 ONLINE
   ata-WDC_WD20EARX-32PASB0_WD-WCAZAJ345272 ONLINE
```

Comment: How was the array configured? (stripe / mirror / raidz)

Comment: What state is the pool in now? It should not have been un-imported when your disk died — the command to sub in a new disk is “zfs replace”, not “zfs import”.

Comment: This is raidz
I have tried zfs replace, but kept getting pool not available.

Comment: Please run `zpool list -v` and `zpool import` and share the output.

Comment: zpool list -v :
"no pools available"

zpool import:
adeolur@Akure:~$ sudo zpool import
   pool: orisha
     id: 3037127084551751026
  state: UNAVAIL
 status: One or more devices are missing from the system.
 action: The pool cannot be imported. Attach the missing
 devices and try again.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-6X
 config:

 orisha                                      UNAVAIL  missing device
   ata-WDC_WD20EZRX-00DC0B0_WD-WMC300898572  ONLINE
   ata-WDC_WD20EZRX-00DC0B0_WD-WMC301198182  ONLINE
   ata-WDC_WD20EARX-32PASB0_WD-WCAZAJ345272  ONLINE

Comment: Please help anyone!!

Comment: That `zpool import` output doesn't make much sense, and it definitely doesn't indicate that the pool is raidz. Taken at face value, it indicates a striped/JBOD pool, but it's missing parts. Please [Edit] this question to incorporate the *actual* output from running `zpool import` (don't worry about exact formatting, but make sure you get all of the data), and also tell us which version of ZFS On Linux you're running (something like `dpkg -l '*zfs*'` should be able to tell you this).